# access to xml nodes and get values xpath

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

on the following xml example I try to access to nodes and get values as follow :
Is it possible to read,compare and look for a specefic strings in xml files using xpath from Matlab ?
I don't find any documentation.

could someone give me an example ?

here to access to description name="localization"> :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<address xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='test.xsd'>
  <lists name="myState">
             <description name="-temp">-20</description>
             <description name="localization">north</description>  
             <description name="-state">false</description> 
      </lists>
    </address>  
    <language language="english" name=""> 
         <description name="population">5000</description> 
    </language>
```

I did : 
    docNode = xmlread(myXMLFILE);
    factory = XPathFactory.newInstance;
    xpath = factory.newXPath;

```
% compile and evaluate the XPath Expression
 expression = xpath.compile(adress/lists/description')
description = expression.evaluate(docNode, XPathConstants.NODE);
descriptionValue = phoneNumberNode.getTextContent  % this gives me -20
```

but here I want to access to ' north ' to get the value 'Noth', how could I procceed ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use predicates in XPath like this: `//address/lists/description[@name="localization"]`. `[]` is used for predicates, `@` is used to select attributes. So the previous expression selects the `description` nodes (below `address/lists`) with an attribute `name` equal to `localization`. There are several websites that can help you with respect to XPath. [W3schools is one.](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) If you need more help on the implementation of XPath used by Matlab, you should look at [Java's implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html). Java can be used directly in Matlab (your code is an example of this) and within Matlab XML processing is done in Java.

Comment: hello , please could you develop more , is there some function that allows me to access to any node value and check xml content ?